# add and edit multiple topics using redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

The use case is there will be add topic button which when clicked should show a form for adding the topic. When user fills the topic form and hits the save button, that topic should be shown in the input box with edit button instead of add. There can be multiple topics. For example, if I have 4 topics already or saved them after adding then they should be displayed with edit button. The way I am doing is not even triggering `handleChange`.

I have created a sandbox for this and here it is

https://codesandbox.io/s/koqqvz2307

The code

```
class FieldArray extends React.Component {
  state = {
    topics: [],
    topic: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    console.log("handleChange", e);
    this.setState({ topic: { ...this.state.topic, topic: e.target.value } });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("state of topics array with multiple topics");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FieldArrayForm
          topics={this.state.topics}
          topic={this.state.topic}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FieldArray;



const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label} />
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
);

const renderTopics = ({
  fields,
  meta: { error },
  handleChange,
  handleSubmit,
  topic
}) => (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push()}>
        Add Topic
      </button>
    </li>
    {fields.map((topicName, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        <span>
          <Field
            name={topicName}
            type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            component={renderField}
            label={`Topic #${index + 1}`}
          />
          <span>
            <button
              type="button"
              title="Remove Hobby"
              onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
            >
              Remove
            </button>
            {topic ? (
              <button type="button" title="Add" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                Edit
              </button>
            ) : (
              <button type="button" title="Add" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                Add
              </button>
            )}
          </span>
        </span>
      </li>
    ))}
    {error && <li className="error">{error}</li>}
  </ul>
);

const FieldArraysForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <FieldArray name="topic" component={renderTopics} />
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: "fieldArrays", // a unique identifier for this form
  validate
})(FieldArraysForm);
```

How do i save and show multiple topics when using redux-form? I tried to take the concept from fieldarray but i could not do it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handleChange` is undefined, and this is why your function isn't being called.

If you are willing that `renderTopics` receive a `handleChange` function, you should pass the `handleChange` prop to the `FieldArray` component (according to [redux-form docs](https://redux-form.com/7.4.0/docs/api/fieldarray.md/#-code-props-object-code-optional-)):

```
const FieldArraysForm = props => {
  const { handleChange, handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <FieldArray name="topic" component={renderTopics} handleChange={handleChange} />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Alternatively, you can simply pass all props from `FieldArraysForm` to the `FieldArray` component:

```
const FieldArraysForm = props => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <FieldArray name="topic" component={renderTopics} {...props} />
  </form>
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.